# Get and compare EditText background color

Tags: android, android-edittext, drawable, background-color

I am developing an Android App where I have a few EditTexts. I am setting the background color of the EditText dynamically with the one I have defined in the res/drawable folder. I want to get the background color of the EditText and compare it with some hex color, e-g if the color is **#ff0000** then change the text color of that EditText to white. This is how I am setting the background color of the EditText:

```
allScaleEditTexts.get(row_col).setBackgroundResource
            (R.drawable.edittext_bgcolor_one);
```

That is how I am getting the background color of the EditText:

```
Drawable scaleEdTxtColor = allScaleEditTexts.get(row_col)
                .getBackground();
```

Now I want to make that comparison like:

```
if(scaleEdTxtColor == #ff0000)
            allScaleEditTexts.get(row_col).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
            allScaleEditTexts.get(row_col).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

I don't know how to go about that comparison. I have tried this:

```
if(scaleEdTxtColor == Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))
```

But then I get the error of comparing a drawable with an int. How can I solve it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBackground%28%29 See what .getBackground returns!

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use

```
if(scaleEdTxtColor == #ff0000)
```

Cause its a drawable.

I think you need to `scaledEdTxtColor.getColorFilter` like you set the color with:

```
scaledEdTxtColor.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Have a look there.